# JSoup Extracting absolute url of a href and a div tag data simultaneously

Tags: java, jsoup

I want to extract two tags  from a website  beside each others(adjacently),  the first tag is  a href  and it should be extracted as the the absolute url . the second tag is a div tag and I should extract 
the data inside it.

I want the output to be as the following

100 USD                            http:\www.somesite..............

200 usd                          http:\www.thesite.............

Why? because later I will insert them into a table in a database .

I tried  with the following code but I couldn't get the absolute url in addition I couldn't get rid of the  tags while I want to extract the data only (without tags).

```
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.bezaat.com/ksa/jeddah/cars/all/1?so=77").get();
    for (Element link : doc.select("div.rightFloat.price,a[abs:href].more-details"))
    {

    String absHref = url.attr("abs:href");
    String attr = link.absUrl("href");
    System.out.println(link);

   }
```

If I try  using 
       System.out.println(link.text())
 in my code I will miss the hyperlink completely  !

Any help please?

Comment: please share the original html.

Comment: I don't undertand what you mean by original html  this the page I try to extract it's data  http://www.bezaat.com/ksa/jeddah/cars/all/1?so=77

Comment: questions here should be self contained. links can die and therefore all info that is needed to answer the question should be included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that Jsoup css selector combinators (i.e. the comma in the selector) guarantees an ordering in the output. At least I would not count on it, even if you find the two elements in the ordering you expect. Instead of using the comma selector, I would first loop over the outer containers that hold the adjacent divs you are interested in. Within each div you can then access the price and link.

something like this. Note, that this is out of my head and untested!

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.bezaat.com/ksa/jeddah/cars/all/1?so=77").get();
for (Element adDiv : doc.select("div.category-listing-normal-ad")){

  Element priceDiv = adDiv.select("div.rightFloat.price").first();
  Element linkA = adDiv.select("a.more-details").first();

  System.out.println(priceDiv.text() + " " + linkA.absUrl("href"));
```

}